# Ошибка во время развёртывания проекта

Tags: java, jsp

Всё было хорошо, проект запускался и работал отлично. В какой-то момент я закрыл его и через некоторое время открыл и выскочила эта ошибка:

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error Tomcat 7.0.82

```
message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:177)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:376)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:376)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp        Не найден класс org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

Comment: Проблема может быть много в чём. Может в jsp-странице ошибка и Tomcat не может её скомпилировать. Может у web-приложения есть конфликт зависимостей. Может Tomcat не имеет прав на запись в директорию, в которую пытается поместить скомпилированный class-файл. И т.д. и т.п.